# Adding Timestamp column in a Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure which takes a user defined table type (UDTT) as one of the parameters, and now I need to call this stored procedure from my C# code.

I've created a dbml file and a class which simulates my UDTT in the database.

Now the issue is there is a column named `Version` which is of type `TIMESTAMP` that is present in the UDTT stored procedure.

This is the structure of my user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.sampletype as
ID INT NULL,
Name String NULL,
Version TIMESTAMP NULL
```

Now I need to pass the UDTT through C# code so I created a `DataTable` and added column **Version**
with type as `byte[]`. I'm sending the value as `NULL`.

Now when I call the stored procedure using classic ADO.net(using cmdparameters, SqlExecuteReader) im getting the below error..

`Cannot insert value to timestamp column.`

Answer (score 1):

Values for the TIMESTAMP data type are auto-generated by SQL Server; you can't INSERT them.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx) the mapping between SQL types and CLR types. I guess you should try to change `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME2`.